# I am wondering about prolog lists

Tags: prolog, list

I'm wondering if there's a way to "shortcut" a list declaration in prolog. Instead of 
[1,2,3]. I'd like to myList = [1,2,3]. so that way I can try to use myList (such as member(X, myList) instead of having to repeat the actual list over and over every place I need it. Is this possible? The fact that I've not found anything on google yet tells me it probably is not, but you never know. Thank you.

Comment: You should accept dasblinkenlight's answer to clear this question from the unanswered list and to give him his props. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular Prolog "fact" in place of such declaration, like this:

```
myList([1, 2, 3]).
```

Now you can use this fact in your program, like this:

```
someRule :-
    myList(L),    /* Unify L with the list from myList fact */
    member(X, L), /* Use L, which is now the [1, 2, 3] list */
    ...
```

This approach lets you avoid hard-coding lists that need to be used from several places in your program.

Comment: @JoshAlcorn You are welcome! If the answer works for your situation, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it. This would indicate to other visitors that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

in a clause, just use a *Variable* (i.e. a symbol starting uppercase) unified to list literal

```
some_rule(Z) :-
  X = [1,2,3], Y = [4,5,6],
  append(X, Y, Z),
  forall(member(M, X), writeln(M)).
```

Otherwise, to share the list among multiple clauses, go with dasblinkelight' hint.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody ever needs an example, here's the code I used to test this, and it works.

```
:- dynamic my_spell_is/1.
my_spell_is(none).

spellslist([fire,ice,lightning,heal]).

casting :-
    my_spell_is(X),
    write('Current spell: '), write(X), nl.

isspell(X) :- (validSpell(X) -> 
my_spell_is(Y),
retract(my_spell_is(Y)),
assert(my_spell_is(X)) ; 
write(X), write(' is not a valid spell.'), nl).

validSpell(X) :-
    spellslist(L),    /* Unify L with the list from spellslist fact */
    member(X, L). /* Use L, which is now the [fire,ice,lightning,heal] list */
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my code. I'm not particularly familiar with the site or how it works and I apologize for posting sloppy code.

Comment: No problem! To format your code, select the lines that you want formatted, and click the `[{}]` button at the top of the editor. You can also add four spaces in front of the code block to have it formatted, or use backward quotes for inline code inside your question.